# Spotify Hello World App not loading

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to get the Spotify Hello World app running (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/) and when I run the app in Spotify it doesn't load anything.  Using the Inspector, it shows nothing in the head and body of the HTML.  I've verified time and again that there actually is something in my index.html file.

I do have a developer's account and I am a premium member.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to get the app to run correctly?

Comment: You should mark a question as being solved by clicking the green check at the best answer. Therefore I will remove the `SOLVED: ` within your question title.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] I just realized when trying to load the application I was typing `spotify:app:Tutorial` when it should have been `spotify:app:tutorial`.  It's case sensitive, yet when its the wrong case it doesn't yield any error, just empty HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your application is found else you would get a not found error. At this rate we can't really tell alot. You might wanna include your manifest and index.html file.
Also if you change something in your manifest you have to kill spotify and restart for it to work properly again.

Comment: I'm just trying to run the sample application [https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/TutorialApp.zip](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/TutorialApp.zip).  I didn't modify the manifest.json or index.html that is included in the tutorial.  

I'm running Spotify version 0.8.2.610.g090a06f8. 
I'm developing on a Mac, OSX Lion.

Comment: [SOLVED] I just realized when trying to load the application I was typing `spotify:app:Tutorial` when it should have been `spotify:app:tutorial`.  It's case sensitive, yet when its the wrong case it doesn't yield any error, just empty HTML.   Thanks for reaching out, hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Using linux (Ubuntu 11.10) the tutorial did not start correctly until I used
consistent caps.
I.e. I changed to "tutorial" instead of "Tutorial" in both app directory name
and in the manifest. Still, the "Spotify" dir in $home needs S in caps.
Then the app started correctly using uri spotify:app:tutorial
I.e. ~/Spotify/tutorial/*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "BundleIdentifier":"tutorial" is in your manifest.json file.